# Como hacer que la clase base conozca qué clase derivada está actuando

Tags: c++, qt

Veamos. Tengo una clase base derivada de `QTableView`, en la que defino la mayoría de los métodos, entre ellos uno llamado `Copiar()`

De esa clase me derivan dos, obteniendo dos tablas con algunas diferencias entre ellas. Cada una de ellas tiene una acción para copiar el contenido, con implementaciones diferentes.

Una forma de hacerlo, es que cada clase derivada tenga su propia función `Copiar()`, la cual llamará al modelo que las sirve y ahí se implementará la función.

Pero me pregunto si yo puedo definir un solo método `Copiar()` en la tabla base, y que -sabiendo de qué tipo es la tabla que llama a la función- haga un casting o una selección a esa tabla derivada de forma que llame al modelo que le corresponde.
Algo como:

```
void TablaBase::Copiar()
{
    if (me ha enviado la señal la tabladerivada1)
    {
         tabladerivada1->model()->Copiar();
    }
    else
    {
         tabladerivada2->model()->Copiar();
    }
}
```

Edito:

Puesto que a esta función de la tabla base se la llama mediante una señal, acabo de ver que puedo acceder al emisor mediante el método `sender()`, en concreto `sender()->parent()` ya que el emisor es una `QAccion`, pero el tipo que me da es el de la tabla base, cuando lo está emitiendo una tabla derivada (si bien mediante una función virtual)

Esta sería la tabla base (pongo la parte representativa):

```
class Filter;

class TablaBase : public QTableView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TablaBase(int nColumnas, QWidget *parent=nullptr);
    bool columnaBloqueada(int columna);
    virtual void MostrarMenuCabecera(QPoint pos)=0;
    virtual void MostrarMenuTabla(QPoint pos)=0;//me centro en este
    QHeaderView* CabeceraDeTabla();
    ~TablaBase();

    int limiteIzquierdo;
    int limiteDerecho;

private slots:
    void Bloquear(int columna);
    void Copiar();
    void Pegar();

public slots:
    void customHeaderMenuRequested(QPoint pos);
    void customTableMenuRequested(QPoint pos);
-------------------
```

Ahora una de las tablas derivadas:

```
class TablaMedCert : public TablaBase
{
public:
    explicit TablaMedCert(int nColumnas, QWidget *parent=nullptr);
    void MostrarMenuCabecera(QPoint pos);
    void MostrarMenuTabla(QPoint pos);

private:
    DelegadosParcialesSubtotales* dlgPS;
    DelegadoMedicionesEstandar* dlgME;
};
```

La implementación de MostrarMenuTabla()

```
void TablaMedCert::MostrarMenuTabla(QPoint pos)
{
    QMenu *menu=new QMenu(this);
    QAction *AccionCopiar = new QAction("Copiar lineas de medición", this);
    QAction *AccionPegar = new QAction("Pegar lineas de medición", this);
    menu->addAction(AccionCopiar);
    menu->addAction(AccionPegar);
    /*copiar*/
    QObject::connect(AccionCopiar, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(Copiar()));
    /*pegar*/
    QObject::connect(AccionPegar, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(Pegar()));
    menu->popup(cabeceraVertical->viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos));
}
```

Y por último la implementación de `Copiar()` en la tabla base (bueno, realmente no hay tal). Pensaba que el `sender()->parent()` sería `TablaMedCert`, con lo que podría hacer un dynamic_cast para que llamase al modelo adecuado, pero veo que realmente el `sender()->parent()` es la tabla base

```
void TablaBase::Copiar()
{
    QObject* obj = sender();
    qDebug()<<obj->parent();
}
```

Comment: ¿`Copiar` será el slot que recibirá la señal? ¿Tiene que ser `void` por la derecha o puedes cambiar su firma?

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir también algo del código de las otras clases? Podría ser útil conocer la jerarquía.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno, al final lo he implementado como sigue.
La tabla base tiene una función `bool Copiar()` que será a la que llamen las tablas derivadas. Por otro lado, el problema lo estaba teniendo (y no sé por qué, la verdad) en el modelo que alimenta a las tablas derivadas, ya que si no se hace casting lo toma como un `AbstractItemModel`

Entonces, mi solución pasa por capturar el `sender`, haciendo un casting a la clase de la Tabla Base. Y luego ver qué modelo (MedicionesModel o PrincipalModel) tiene esa tabla haciendo de nuevo un casting a cada uno de los posibles. He cambiado el tipo a `bool`
El código es el siguiente, espero que esté bien y sirva:

```
bool TablaBase::Copiar()
{
    TablaBase* tabla = qobject_cast<TablaBase*>(sender()->parent());
    if (MedicionesModel* mod = qobject_cast<MedicionesModel*>(tabla->model()))
    {
        return mod->Copiar();
    }
    else if (PrincipalModel* mod = qobject_cast<PrincipalModel*>(tabla->model()))
    {
        return mod->Copiar();
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre una posible solución, muy fácil de implementar: utiliza un campo en la clase base para indicar desde que derivada estás llamando:

```
class Base {
private:
  int mDerived;

protected:    
  Base( int d ) : mDerived( d ) { }

public:
  virtual algo( );
};

class Hija: public Base {
public:
  // Cambiamos el número según la clase hija que seamos.
  Hija( ) : Base( 1 ) { }
};

void Base::algo( ) {
  ...
  if( mDerived == ... ) {
    // Codigo dependiendo de la clase hija.
  } else if( mDerived == ... ) {
    ...
  }
}
```

También podrías utilizar `typeid( *this )` si tus clases tienen métodos virtuales.

Comment: Hola. Pensé en esa implementación también, pero quería evitarla por no tener que usar un parámetro poco claro. Al final he conseguido una implementación en base a averiguar el `sender`

Answer (score 0):

En C++ puedes hacer que una función se comporte de forma diferente según el tipo concreto de objeto que estés utilizando y esto se consigue con la palabra `virtual`:

```
struct A
{
  virtual void func() // Solo es necesario en la classe base
  { std::cout << "A\n"; }
};

struct B : A
{
  void func()
  { std::cout << "B\n"; }
};

struct C : B
{
  void func()
  { std::cout << "C\n"; }
};

struct D : B
{
  void func()
  { std::cout << "D\n"; }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<A*> lista;
  lista.push_back(new A);
  lista.push_back(new B);
  lista.push_back(new C);
  lista.push_back(new D);

  for( int i=0; i<lista.size(); i++ )
  {
    A* puntero = lista[i];
    puntero->func();
  }
}
```

Salida:

```
A
B
C
D
```

En Qt esto funciona también con los slots. Aplicado a tu caso el código podría lucir más o menos así:

```
class TablaBase : public QTableView
{
private slots:
    virtual void Copiar();
};

class TablaMedCert : public TablaBase
{

private slots:
  // En la clase base esta funcion es virtual
  // En esta implementacion pones el comportamiento especifico para TablaMedCert
  void Copiar(); 
};
```

Comment: Hola eferion. Pero eso no es (creo) realmente lo que quiero. Yo me preguntaba (si es posible) si una función Copiar() en la tabla base sería capaz de discriminar la tabla derivada que ha hecho la llamada a esa función y llamar al modelo que le corresponde.

Comment: @user3733164 Una clase base no debería conocer la existencia de sus clases derivadas. ¿Lo que intentas es que dos tablas se comuniquen entre sí? Deberías buscar una forma más limpia de hacerlo que seguro que la hay (si expones amplia y detalladamente qué es lo que necesitas posiblemente a alguien se le ocurra una solución elegante).

Comment: pues tienes razón. No le doy más vueltas y definiré una función Copiar() por cada una de las dos tablas derivadas. La verdad es que la duda me ha venido al ver que las implementaciones de la función Copiar() son idénticas en ambas tablas derivadas. Sólo son una llamada a una función del modelo: *tabladerivada->model()->copiar()* De ahí se me ocurrió que se podía hacer una implementación única en la clase base.

Comment: @user3733164 puedes tener una implementación común en la clase base y llamar a dicha funcionalidad desde las derivada haciendo `TablaBase::Copiar();`. Incluso si el código fuese el mismo pero con diferentes _parámetros_ podrías llamar a una función común de `TablaBase` pasando los parámetros correspondientes.

Answer (score 0):

Bajo la asumpción que no quieres que tu método "copiar" sea `virtual` (tus objetos ya son polimórficos así que... no sé por qué no ir hacia la solución de eferion, más eficiente que la tuya), si no te importa que la clase base sea paramétrica:

```
template<class derivada>
class TablaBase : public QTableView
{ ... };

class TablaDerivada1 : public TablaBase<TablaDerivada>
{ ... };
```

Dentro de TablaBase, ya tienes el tipo de la derivada. Tu función copiar sería:

```
if (std::is_same<derivada, TablaDerivada1>::value)
    un_metodo();
else
    el_otro();
```

Si no quieres que sea paramétrica, entonces vete a una solución virtual:

```
if (dynamic_cast<TablaDerivada1*>(this) != nullptr)
     un_metodo();
else
     el_otro();
```

Como posibilidad adicional, también podrías trabajar con `typeid` o `type_index`, etc...